# Find values for a given mean

Tags: python

I'm pretty new to python and trying to generate a defined number of numbers (e.g 3 numbers) which mean is equal to a given value. 
For example, let's say I'm trying to get different list of 3 numbers whose  means equals 10, which would make these lists for example :
(5,10,15) & (0, 0, 30) & (5,5,20).

As I fixed the number of elements in the list I know I could use only the sum but even for that I can't find how to compute different list with the same sum in a pythonic way.

Edit :
I want to generate a defined number of list, not all the possible combination and now that I think about it, it should be only integers

Comment: Do you want to generate any one list or all possible lists of size n with mean value lets say S?

Comment: the question is not clear. Does (40, -4, -6) is valid? do you accept decimals or only integers? in these last cases there is an infinity of combinations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go.
This is only for positive integers with no duplicates

```
def make_lists(mean):
    'without duplicates'
    for i in range(0, mean+1):
        for j in range(i, mean+1): 
            k = mean * 3 - i - j

            assert (k+i+j) / 3.0 == float(mean), ((k+i+j) / 3.0) #just testing
            yield (i,j, k)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    print( list(make_lists(10)))
```